# TextBoxFor character encoding (Scandinavian letters)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm binding a Model ti editing on an MVC view using TextBoxFor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Company)
```

assuming that the company name is Andenæs  (or any scandvian name like Lønø), the TextBoxFor encoded it like the screenshot below:

[image: decoding problem]

how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

> the TextBoxFor encoded

You are confusing `TextBoxFor` and `LabelFor`. The `LabelFor` helper (which is what you are using here) simply outputs the value of your model property directly to the HTML page. In order to do that safely it needs to HTML encodes this value. Which is why you are seeing this `Anden&#230;s`. This is safe and browsers will correctly render it. HTML is meant to be read and interpreted by browsers, not humans, so as long as the human looking at the browser sees the correct text this is just fine.

This being said there's no way to change this behavior for the built-in helpers. If you need to achieve that you will have to write custom helpers and manually encode everything (totally not recommended).

---

UPDATE:

According to what you have shown in the comments section you are nowhere using any TextBoxFor helper. You are using some custom editor template in which you hardcoded your input field and incorrectly encoded the value:

```
<input type="text" class="string @ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" value="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue" name="@string.Format("{0}-{1}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name, ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)" id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix" dafault-value="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName" />
```

whereas you should have used the TextBox helper to ensure that the value is properly encoded:

```
@Html.TextBox(
    "", 
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, 
    new {
        id = ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix,
        @class = "string " + ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName",
        dafault_value = ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName
    }
)
```

Comment: Oh then it seems that the value of the Company string is not `Andenæs` but it is already HTML encoded as `Anden&#230;s`. You will have to fix your server side code or the place from which you are retrieving those values. I suspect that you have already corrupt HTML encoded data in your database.

Comment: not really. the problem is in the view. I tested it. The model.Company is sent to the view in a correct format "Andenæs". The same in the database. 
here is the editor template i use:
    <input type="text" 
       class="string @ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" 
       value="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue"
       name="@string.Format("{0}-{1}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.Name, ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)"
       id="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix"
       dafault-value="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName" 
        />

Comment: Well there you go!!! Why did you lie that you are using the TextBoxFor helper??? That's absolutely not true. The TextBoxFor helper would never behave as described here. You are using some custom template editor in which you manually hardcoded your `<input>` field and incorrectly encoded the value. Never hardcode input fields like that. Just use the built-in helpers such as TextBox for example. In Razor the `@` function that you used is performing HTML encoding of the value which is not what you need for input fields.